# Does a solution better than O(N^2) exist Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

```py
def get_money_spent(keyboards, drives, budget):

    kb = sorted(keyboards)
    dr = sorted(drives)
    if budget - kb[0] <= 0 or budget - dr[0] <= 0:
        return (-1)

    most_spent = 0
    for keyboard in kb:
        for usb in dr:
        if (keyboard + usb > most_spent) and (keyboard + usb <= budget):
            most_spent = keyboard + usb

    return most_spent
```

My solution ^^^

> A person wants to determine the most expensive computer keyboard and USB drive that can be purchased with a given budget. Given price lists for keyboards and USB drives and a budget, find the cost to buy them. If it is not possible to buy both items, return -1.
>
> Example
>
> budget = 60
>
> keyboards = [40, 50, 60]
>
> drives = [5, 8, 12]
>
> The person can buy a 40 keyboard + 12 USB drive = 52, or a 50 keyboard + 8 USB
>
> drive = 58.
>
> In this case, the code should return the most expensive option: 58.
>
> Function Description
>
> Complete the function get_money_spent, which has the following parameters:
>
> The maximum that can be spent, or -1 if it isn't possible to buy both items.

Comment: There is a solution better than the product of the sizes of the two input arrays. Iterate over each keyboard, then find the (only) the largest drive such that the price of both is below the budget, instead of possibly scanning all drives. Notice that with some precomputation, you can do better than linear time on the second step.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the code block.

Comment: You might be interested in: Questions tagged [knapsack-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knapsack-problem)

Comment: There could be several answers. Suppose 40$ keyboard and 20$ drive is the best, what if there is also a 20$ keyboard and 40$ drive? How to chose among solutions of the same amount? Aside: @wLui155 gave you the best hint to lower the complexity (sort...).

Answer (score 0):

this algorithm can be trivially improved by using `bisect` to find the most expensive usb drive under budget, which will lead to O(n log m) complexity.

```
import bisect

def get_money_spent(keyboards, drives, budget):
    drives.sort()
    most_spent = -1
    for keyboard in sorted(keyboards):
        index_of_max_affordable_usb = bisect.bisect_right(drives, budget-keyboard)
        if not index_of_max_affordable_usb:
            # reached the keyboard making all drives unaffordable
            break
        most_spent = max(most_spent, keyboard+drives[index_of_max_affordable_usb-1])

    return most_spent
```

However, there is also an O(n+m) alternative, using two pointers. In this case, instead of doing a full O(log m) search from scratch, we are reusing results of the previous scan, gradually incrementing/decrementing component index until the first match:

```
def get_money_spent(keyboards, drives, budget):
    # note that items in the iterator can be consumed only once
    drives = iter(sorted(drives, reverse=True))
    most_spent = -1
    for keyboard in sorted(keyboards):
        for drive in drives:
            if drive+keyboard <= budget:
                most_spent = max(most_spent, drive+keyboard)
                break

    return most_spent
```

Comment: `sorted` does not have linear time complexity.

Comment: @trincot Perhaps, you're right. It's `O(n log n + m log m)` in the second case and `O(n log n + m log m + n log m)` in the first